# SQL: Unrecongnized statement near conditional (IF)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've never used IF's before in SQL. I need to update a row where institution is a specific number if it exists and insert it if it doesn't. In order to avoid using first a select and then a insert or update I wanted to try my hand at an IF statement. I figured from what I've read in the documentation that it should go something like this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT evaluations FROM tEvaluations WHERE institution = 0))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tEvaluations (institution,evaluations) VALUES (0,0)
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE tEvaluations SET evaluations = 10 WHERE institution = 0
END
```

However I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tEvaluations (institution,evaluations) VALUES (0,0)
END' at line 2
```

I'm trying to run this query in phpmyadmin to test out how the query should be.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh `phpmyadmin` imples MySQL - but it could be legacy MySQL 5 or modern MySQL 8 - which are very different to each toher.

Comment: @jarlh I guess MySQL looking at the error message *check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server*

Comment: I'm using MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `if..else` block in normal SQL statement unless it's inside a procedural block. To me looks like you are looking for [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) like

```
INSERT INTO tEvaluations (institution,evaluations) VALUES (0,0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE evaluations = 10;
```

Per documentation, either of your column should have a `UNIQUE` constraint defined against it. Quoting from documentation

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be
>   inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY
>   KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs. For example, if column a is
>   declared as UNIQUE and contains the value 1

Comment: I run you query twice. Just as it is and it inserted (0,0) twice. Instead of only once and then update. Do I need to create a constraint that institution,evaluations is a unique pair or something like that?

Comment: @aarelovich Yes, see edit in answer and moreover, check the documentation linked in the answer for more details